# golang recursive json to struct?

Tags: json, go, struct, slice

I used to write python, just started to contact golang

my json for example,children unknow numbers,may be three ,may be ten。

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaa",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbb",
        "children": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "ccc",
            "children": [{
                "id": 4,
                "name": "ddd",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

i write struct

```
    
type AutoGenerated []struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Children []struct {
        ID       int    `json:"id"`
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        Children []struct {
            ID       int    `json:"id"`
            Name     string `json:"name"`
            Children []struct {
                ID       int           `json:"id"`
                Name     string        `json:"name"`
                Children []interface{} `json:"children"`
            } `json:"children"`
        } `json:"children"`
    } `json:"children"`
}
```

but i think this too stupid。
how to optimize？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse the `AutoGenerated` type in its definition:

```
type AutoGenerated []struct {
    ID       int           `json:"id"`
    Name     string        `json:"name"`
    Children AutoGenerated `json:"children"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
var o AutoGenerated

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &o); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(o)
```

<sup>(`src` is your JSON input string.)</sup>

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/WqatdrB-1sN)):

```
[{1 aaa [{2 bbb [{3 ccc [{4 ddd []}]}]}]}]
```

Also it's easier to understand and work with if `AutoGenerated` itself is not a slice:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    ID       int             `json:"id"`
    Name     string          `json:"name"`
    Children []AutoGenerated `json:"children"`
}
```

Then using it / testing it:

```
var o []AutoGenerated

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &o); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(o)
```

Outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-tXXgpgtbKO).